# convolution after dynamic transpose (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, transpose

I'm trying to implement the architecture in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05957.pdf (in the top of page 3)

The problem is that, my dataset contains different size of images, and while trying to apply convolution after transpose with dynamic shapes, the unknown shapes will lead to error:

```
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (fuse01/weights) must be fully defined, but instead was (3, 3, ?, 10).
```

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

slim = tf.contrib.slim


def conv(input_batch, nb_kernel, nb_row, nb_col, scope_name, strides=None):
    if strides is None:
        strides = 1
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d], padding='SAME', stride=strides):
        out = slim.conv2d(input_batch, nb_kernel, [nb_row, nb_col], scope=scope_name)
    return out


def conv_trans(input_batch, nb_kernel, nb_row, nb_col, name_scope, stride, output_like):
    with tf.name_scope(name_scope):
        weights = get_weights([nb_row, nb_col, nb_kernel, input_batch.get_shape()[3].value])
        out_shape = tf.shape(output_like)
        out_shape = [input_batch.get_shape()[0].value, out_shape[1], out_shape[2], nb_kernel]
        output = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input_batch, weights, out_shape, [1, stride, stride, 1])
        return output


def get_weights(shape):
    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(dtype=tf.float32)
    variable = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=shape), name='weights')
    return variable

a = np.ones([1, 165, 167, 3], np.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None, 3])

net = conv(x, 10, 3, 3, 'conv1')
net = conv(net, 20, 3, 3, 'conv2', strides=2)
skip_01 = net
net = conv(net, 40, 3, 3, 'conv3', strides=2)
skip_02 = net
net = conv(net, 80, 3, 3, 'conv4', strides=2)
skip_03 = net
net = conv(net, 160, 3, 3, 'conv5', strides=2)
up_01 = conv_trans(net, 30, 3, 3, 'test', 2, skip_03) # shape: (?, ?, ?, ?)
fuse_01 = tf.concat([skip_03, up_01], 3) # shape: (1, ?, ?, ?)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

print fuse_01
print sess.run(fuse_01, feed_dict={x: a})

fuse_01 = conv(fuse_01, 10, 3, 3, 'fuse01')  # this will cause error
```

Is there any way to get the specific shape of the tensor after applying `conv_transpose`?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that, my dataset contains different size of images, and while trying to ....

The easiest approach is just to convert all the images to the same size at the very beginning. You are trying to remove rain/snow from the image, so the size of the image should not matter.